# Passing a hash to a subroutine without changing it input

Tags: perl

I'm trying to debug some strange behavior while handling with a hash in `Perl`.
I'm passing a hash (not ref) to a subroutine and for some reason it updates it.

```
some_sub($a,%{$hash});
sub some_sub {
    my ($a,%hash) = @_;
    my @struct;
    while (my ($dir, $data) = each %hash) {
        foreach my $id (keys(%{$data})) {
            my $entry = $data->{$id};
            $entry->{id} = $id;
            my $parent = $data->{$entry->{id}};
            unless ($parent) {
                push @struct, $entry
            } else {
                push @{$parent->{children}},$entry;
            }
        }
    }
}
my %h= %{$hash};
print Dumper(\%h);
```

The sub `some_sub` does change `%hash` but only for the inner scope, so it should not change the data of the outside `%hash`. Also, I pass the hash as a hash and not as a hash ref. I suspected the sub `some_sub` inserts memory addresses into the `%hash`, but I'm not sure.

How should I debug and solve this issue?

**EDIT**: I also tried to pass a hash ref to the subroutine and do a dereferencing of the hash ref into another hash while doing all of the operations on the new hash.

Comment: without sample input data it's not possible to give an answer, but, you *are* mutating things in several places. `$entry->{id} = $id;`, and both `push`s

Comment: @user3243135 Thanks for the replay. My question is why it changes `%hash` if I passed it to the sub, as a hash and not as a hash ref.

Answer (score 9):

Every value in a hash is a scalar. If you have a nested hash, the inner hash is stored as a scalar - a hash reference. Therefore, when changing the nested structures, the changes happen in the referenced hash, which is referenced from the original hash, too.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub change {
    my %hash2 = @_;
    for my $key (keys %hash2) {
        ++$_ for values $hash2{$key};
    }
}

my %hash = (a => {b => 12, c => 24});
change(%hash);
use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%hash;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => {
                   'b' => 13,
                   'c' => 25
                 }
        };
```

The process of obtaining a structure that's similar as the original but contains different references is called *cloning* or *deep copying*. See [Clone](http://p3rl.org/Clone) or `dclone` from [Storable](http://p3rl.org/Storable).

Answer (score 4):

Arguments are passed to a function as a flat list of scalars, so

```
some_sub($a, %{$hashref})
```

has the keys and values of the hash passed as a list after `$a`

```
some_sub($a, key, value, ...);
```

since a function call always takes merely a list of scalars.
These key-value pairs are assigned to a hash in the function so when you work with that hash you directly use references from the calling code, your hash values. So data in the caller gets changed if those references are written to.

The details aren't given but in general one way to avoid changing caller's data in the sub is by introducing local variables for each reference the processing encounters. But then those may themselves contain references so you'd still need to be very careful.

It is simpler to make a full deep copy of the hash, ff the data structure isn't huge. For example

```
use Storable qw(dclone);

some_sub($v, $hashref);

sub some_sub {
    my ($var, $hr) = @_;
    my $cloned_hashref = dclone($hr);
    # work away with $cloned_hashref
}
```